# java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack while running JUnit Test cases

Tags: java, maven, junit, hbase

Hi I'm new to java and I found this error while running my JUnit test cases. I'm getting error in the DAO class of my application, I'm going to call my class 'TestDao' class. I'm using eclipse as my IDE but I get this error when I do 'mvn clean install' which also runs my test cases. The error stack is below from surefire reports:

> java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
>
> Exception Details:
>
> Location:
>           com/services/test/dao/TestDao.deleteAuditLogsForLabel(Ljava/lang/String;)V
>   @62: invokespecial
>
> Reason:
>           Type org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SubstringComparator (current frame, stack[5]) is not assignable to
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ByteArrayComparable
>
> Current Frame:
>      bci: @62
>
> flags: { }
>
> locals: { com/services/test/dao/TestDao, java/lang/String, org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable,
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList, java/lang/String,
>   java/lang/String, org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SubstringComparator }
>
> stack: { uninitialized 42, uninitialized 42, [B, [B, org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/CompareFilter$CompareOp,
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SubstringComparator }

Below is the TestDao.deleteAuditLogsForLabel method.

```
public void deleteAuditLogsForLabel(String netElementId) {
    try {

        HTable auditlogTable = new HbaseCore()
                .getHtable(DatabaseConstants.AUDITTABLE);
        FilterList filterList = new FilterList(
                FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
        String columnFamily = DatabaseConstants.AUDITTABLE;
        String netId = netElementId;
        SubstringComparator netElementIdComparator = new SubstringComparator(
                netId);

        SingleColumnValueFilter subObjectNameFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
                Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily),
                Bytes.toBytes(DatabaseConstants.SUB_OBJECT_NAME),
                CompareOp.EQUAL, netElementIdComparator);

        SingleColumnValueFilter subCategoryFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
                Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily),
                Bytes.toBytes(DatabaseConstants.SUB_CATEGORY),
                CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(Constants.SYSTEM_LABEL));

        SingleColumnValueFilter usernameFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
                Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily),
                Bytes.toBytes(DatabaseConstants.USER_NAME),
                CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(Constants.MACHINE_NAME));

        SingleColumnValueFilter categoryFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
                Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily),
                Bytes.toBytes(Constants.CATEGORY), CompareOp.EQUAL,
                Bytes.toBytes(Constants.LABEL_MODULE));

        filterList.addFilter(subObjectNameFilter);
        filterList.addFilter(subCategoryFilter);
        filterList.addFilter(usernameFilter);
        filterList.addFilter(categoryFilter);

        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.setFilter(filterList);
        ResultScanner resultScanner = auditlogTable.getScanner(scan);
        List<Delete> deletes = new ArrayList<Delete>();
        for (Result result : resultScanner) {

            String rowID = Bytes.toString(result.getRow());

            Delete delete = new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(rowID));

            deletes.add(delete);

        }
        auditlogTable.delete(deletes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.logRuntimeError(e);
    }
}
```

I read about how to resolve the 'java.lang.VerifyError' error
[here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-verifyerror-how-to-solve-verifyerror/). But a VerifyError is thrown where a class has a dependency
on some other class and that class has incompatibly changed after the compilation. But both the SubstringComparator and ByteArrayComparable classes are part of the same jar file hbase_client[v0.98.3-hadoop2].

Also the application is working fine. Its just the test cases which is throwing this error. Can someone please explain what is the problem?

Comment: Show us `TestDao.deleteAuditLogsForLabel`

Comment: Which IDE / Java compiler do you use to compile your JUnit test?

Comment: An older Eclipse version? Could be an Eclipse JDT compiler bug (it had several of these). I would try with javac and/or a current Eclipse version first (javac also had this problem, see [here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8006684) for example).

Comment: Hi @StefanZobel . Thank you for replying. I also tried it using javac but it didn't work. Moreover I'm using maven to build these test cases.

Comment: Do you have any bytecode post-processing steps (obfuscation or something similar)? Did you try using other (older/newer) versions of javac? What are the versions of the JRE and of javac that you use now? I'm asking because the most likely reason for errors like this is that the bytecode is broken, most often it is a compiler bug or an obfuscator that is causing this.

Comment: Another possibility: are you sure that the JUnit test really has the same hbase_client.jar on its classpath that was used for compilation?